# (Django - Python) Problems with timedelta saving form

Tags: python, django, datetime, save, timedelta

I have a problem with my auction site because when I publish an auction the function doesn't save my variable correctly, these are my codes:

- views.py

  ```
  import datetime
  from datetime import timedelta

  def publishAuction(request):

    user=request.user

    form = auctionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if request.method=="POST":

        if form.is_valid():

            auction=form.save(commit=False)
            auction.advertiser=user
            auction.startDate=datetime.datetime.now()
            auction.endDate=auction.startDate+timedelta(days=1)
            auction.endPrice=request.POST.get("startPrice")
            auction.save()
            return redirect("../")

        else:

            form=auctionForm()
  ```
- models.py

  ```
  class Auction(models.Model):

    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='auction_advertiser', null=True)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='auction_winner', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = models.TextField()
    startPrice = models.FloatField(null=True)
    endPrice = models.FloatField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    endDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  ```

The publication is done correctly, everything except endDate that is always equal to startDate...

I have tried also with datetime.datetime.now instead of auction.startDate or datetime.timedelta(days=1) but when I get the value in the shell is always the same...

In the scratch.py file I write the same codes and it works, I don't know why doesn't work in the function... :S

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `auto_now_add=True` on your `endDate` field, which renders field uneditable and set as now(). From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.
> Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is
> always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. **So
> even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it
> will be ignored**.

Comment: Oh god it's true, what an oversight, I hadn't really noticed! Thanks a lot! ^^